# asterisk python ami client disconnection problem

Tags: python, sockets, asteriskami

im having a recurring disconnection problem with ami action when i use muteaudio

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-481' coro=<AsyncServer._handle_event_internal() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/socketio/asyncio_server.py:522> exception=IndexError('list index out of range')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/socketio/asyncio_server.py", line 524, in _handle_event_internal
    r = await server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/socketio/asyncio_server.py", line 558, in _trigger_event
    ret = await handler(*args)
  File "main_v2.py", line 155, in click
    pabx.para_intercom_bg()
  File "/home/asterisk/apiinter/classes/pabxmanager.py", line 281, in para_intercom_bg
    retorno = ret.split("Local/s@chegou"+str(ramal)+"-")[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
Desmutou saida de audio pro 11 None
CLICK SOCKET {'ramal': '12', 'token': 'T*$jA@f8HDpWZeqmBBdgvhN_z'}
atendimento
set intercomstatus true e muda pra fora
Toca intercom BG
---------ERRO---------
<class 'ConnectionResetError'> pabxmanager.py 144
-
[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
Logme: 2023-10-16 19:43:08 -> erro: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer, kwargs: <class 'ConnectionResetError'>, pabxmanager.py, 144
```

please some one can help me? or some one knows the same commando directly in asterisk Cli ?

my code is very simple

in my class i do de login:

```
self.ami_client = AMIClient(address=self.ami_host,port=self.ami_port)
self.ami_client.login(username=self.ami_user,secret=self.ami_pass)
self.ami_client.add_event_listener(self.ami_event_listener)
```

and when i receice a comand to mute the one direction audio for one channel i do that:

```
action = SimpleAction(
                                        'MuteAudio',
                                        Channel='PJSIP/11-00000023',
                                        Exten='11', 
                                        Direction='out',
                                        State='on'                   
                                )
                                future = self.ami_client.send_action(action)
                                response = future.response
```

in some point of the execution this codes stops with that error.